# How to add extra form fields outside the form declaration block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

**The main goal:** Allow plugins, gems to add additional form fields to predefined forms.

For example, application has a devise login form:
`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, ...) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  ...
<% end %>`

Marketing department wants to start a campaign for the next 2 days (ex: register with a promo code and get X bonus points). So we need to add an additional `promo code` field to ALL our registration forms.

Is there a way to add an extra field to the form from my rails-plugin/railtie, and define a `on_submit` callback method (to take action on my additional field data)?

**Benefits:**

- it allows removing the functionality in 2 days or a week simply by removing it from gem file
- guarantee that core site's functionality is not broken, it simply falls back to the original functionality
- guarantee that a developer has not left any code somewhere in the main app
- plugin/railtie takes care of the saving/updating data that belongs to it

Looked at ActionView code, and it seems there is no built in way of doing it. What are your thoughts?

NOTE: Drupal's `form_alter` hooks are a great example.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your idea to isolate this code in a gem/railtie/engine is excellent. I think your best bet may be to monkey patch the form_for method and stick in the extra field. Regarding the on-submit trigger, if you're on Rails 3.1 and are using the asset pipeline, you can have the gem serve javascript as well, although that would require a small change in your `application.js` to require the gem's js file, e.g. `require 'promo/application.js`, if the gem were called "promo".

Take a look at the docs for [Customized Form Builder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Customized+form+builders)

Here's some rough idea how this could work, although I haven't tried this code. I'd put this in the promo.rb file that sub-classes `Railtie` or `Engine`.

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do

  module ActionView
    module Helpers
      module FormHelper
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
          alias_method_chain :form_for, :promo_code
        end

        module InstanceMethods

          def form_for_with_promo_code(record, options = {}, &proc)
            output = form_for_without_promo_code(record, options.merge(builder: FormBuilderWithPromoCode), proc)
            # See file: actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb for details
            # the output will have "</form>" as the last thing, strip that off here and inject your input field
            promo_field = content_tag :input, name: 'promo_code'  # you can also run this through the proc if you want access to the object
            output.sub(%r{</form>$},promo_field+'</form>')
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Down the road, esp. if your marketing department may run more campaigns, you may even want to change the app's forms, to point to a specific builder that you can override from a gem without the monkey patching here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the "Customized Form Builder" direction. Your answer is the closest to what I want. I think I'll write a custom form builder that adds hidden field (similar in idea to "_method") and add a rack middleware that checks for that field and triggers additional methods in my Engines/plugins.

Comment: Diving deeper in the Rails code I found `extra_tags_for_form` method that adds `authenticity_token` tags. I'll submit a pull request that will allow other methods to add additional tags. But I got a feeling this should have already been done by smarter people than myself.
Is there way to add a tag to all forms (the way `protect_from_forgery` does)?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I had the same thought, but I couldn't find a hook for that. I was thinking of hacking fields_for to do this, but it wasn't obvious that this wouldn't have side effects. I'm as surprised as you are that this hasn't been done. I also checked the `simple_form` code, but the just wrap the native form helpers and set up their own API.

Answer (score 1):

Idea in steps:

1) Define a model such as AdditionalField (id, field_name, field_type, default_value, is_required)

2) then create a function like:

```
def self.for_form(my_form_name = nil)
 if my_form_name.nil?
  self.all
else
  self.find(:all, :contitions => {:form_type => my_form_name.type} # or whatever selection criteria
end
```

3) then you can iterate over the found AdditionalFields and build the correct field types as needed.

I used this solution for a comparison website where they needed to configure the questionnaires for each different comparison type.

Here's the render code I used, you'll need to amend it to suit your situation.
relationships are:

```
convention -< booking >- user
convention -< convention_question
booking -< guests
guest -< guest_answers
```

QuestionsHelper

```
def render_guest_questions(guest, convention_question)      

    fields_for "booking[guest_answer_attributes][]", convention_question do |m|
      case convention_question.display_type
      when "Text"
        '<td>' + text_field_tag("booking[guest_answer_attributes][convention_question_#{guest.id}_#{convention_question.id}]") + '</td>'
      when "Boolean"
        '<td>' + hidden_field_tag("booking[guest_answer_attributes][convention_question_#{guest.id}_#{convention_question.id}]", "No") + check_box_tag("booking[guest_answer_attributes][convention_question_#{guest.id}_#{convention_question.id}]", "Yes") + '</td>'
      end
    end

end
```

Controller

```
# TURN GUEST/QUESTIONS INTO guest answers
if params[:booking] && !params[:booking].blank? && !params[:booking][:guest_answer_attributes].blank?
    params[:booking][:guest_answer_attributes].each do |k,v|
      handle_answers(k, v)
    end
end

def handle_answers(k, v)
  x = k.mb_chars.split(/_/)
  g_id = x[2]
  q_id = x[3]
  item = GuestAnswer.find_or_create_by_guest_id_and_convention_question_id(
                  {:guest_id => g_id,
                  :convention_question_id => q_id, 
                  :answer => v})
 end
```

Comment: How did you save submitted data?

Comment: I saved it by creating user_answers table. `UserAnswer` which has `belongs_to :user; belongs_to AdditionalField;` with the fields of `user_id, additional_field_id, answer_value`

Comment: uzbekjon - I added the code i used for the project i did. Feel free to ask more if it doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0):

in this case new gem should be created that will -

1. add promo_code to user model and make it accessible
2. override devise form to incorporate promo code input (simply copy paste view form and add promo field)
3. Add necessary validations & extra processing (callbacks) inside user model (meta-programming on user class)

We are not doing any changes within main application hence we are safe.

Comment: Yes, this method would workout great if you have only one "change". But what if you have more than one plugin that wants to change the form. The method implies that developers will need to keep track of all the gems and plugins that are currently changing the form.

Comment: Of-course track of external engines and what they are doing needs to be kept while doing further changes.